# Regular Expression that Matches values for YYYYMM

Tags: .net, regex, pattern-matching

I need some **regular expression** for **.net** that matches the following *pattern*: **YYYYMM**

Where:

- YYYY is a *year* between 2000 and 2049
- *MM* is a *month* between 01 and 12

I have done the below one the problem with this, is that it includes invalid month values.

```
[2]{1}[0]{1}[0-4]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work: `20[0-4]\d(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`

To match a month, you need to look for either:

- a `0` followed by anything from `[1-9]` *or*
- a `1` followed by anything from `[0-2]`

If you want want to capture the year and month, `(20[0-4]\d)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`

If you don't want to capture either year or month, `20[0-4]\d(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])`

If you want to capture them with names, `(?<year>20[0-4]\d)(?<month>0[1-9]|1[0-2])`

Comment: One minor tweak you might consider: adding a ?: inside the parentheses to keep it from creating a capture group just for the month, like `20[0-4][0-9](?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])`.

Answer (score 4):

```
(?<year>20[0-4]\d(?<month>(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])))
```

this is the regex I'll separate in two named groups

Comment: I have never ear about named groups, probably this could be useful for more complex patterns

Comment: @Arce, indeed, groups (named or otherwise) are useful for both simple and complex patterns, if you need to extract the matched values for later use.

Comment: Yes named groups is useful because after you find match with Regex class you can extract the month and year for example match.Groups["year"]

Comment: Good idea, but `00` is not a valid month.